# Best practice to secure spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: angularjs, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

Lets say i have a **table z** holding **column a,b,c.**

Column a and b can be used by any authorized user and column c can be only used by admins.

My hibernate entity is based on table z. My spring mvc controller has a read and write method. I can secure the mvc controllers using roles using spring security.

The problem is...my client (angular talking via rest/json to the controller) can access all columns by setting the value for c (even when the client frontend does not provide this explicitly) by simple setting a json object and sending it to the controllers write method. Also calling the read method will give back the c columns value to any user.

What is a good practice to access that table based on roles?

Ok, below a conrete example:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hotel")
@XmlRootElement
public class Hotel extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String street;
    private String houseNo;
    private String postalcode;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String shortDesc;
    private Boolean landing; // admin acceess only
}
```

Backend Facade:

```
@Component
public class HotelAccessImpl extends BackendBaseAccess implements HotelAccess {
    @Autowired
    private AccountAccess accountAccess;

    @Override
    public List<Hotel> findAll() {
        TypedQuery<Hotel> query = getEm().createQuery("FROM Hotel WHERE DELETED = false ORDER BY CREATED DESC",
                Hotel.class);
        List<Hotel> results = query.getResultList();
        return results;
    }

@Override
@Transactional(value = "transactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Hotel upsert(Hotel hotel) {
    if (find(hotel.getId()) == null) {
        getEm().persist(hotel);
    } else {
        hotel = getEm().merge(hotel);
    }
    getEm().flush();
    return hotel;
}

}
```

API (Controller, where i restrict access "only" on method level)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("hotel")
public class HotelController extends BaseController {
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HotelController.class);

@Autowired
private FileAccess fileAccess;
@Autowired
private HotelAccess hotelAccess;
@Autowired
private MailAccess mailAccess;


@RequestMapping(value = "list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Hotel>> findAll() {
    logger.info("FindAll");
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Hotel>>(hotelAccess.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "upsert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Hotel> upsert(@RequestBody Hotel hotel) {
    logger.info("Upsert: " + hotel.getName());
    if (isAuthorized(hotel.getAccount())) {
        Hotel response = hotelAccess.upsert(hotel);
        if (response.isInitial()) {
            mailAccess.sendHotelUpsert(response);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Hotel>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
@Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN" })
@RequestMapping(value = "delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Hotel> delete(@RequestBody Hotel hotel) {
    logger.info("Delete: " + hotel.getId());
    boolean deleted = hotelAccess.delete(hotel);
    return (deleted) ? new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK) : new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: Need to scale this down to a more specific problem. See [ask]

Comment: added some code, hope this gives more explanation now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider securing the marshalling and unmarshalling of your entity data.

In other words, for non-administrator users, you'd want to only marshall fields `A` and `B` to the client and unmarshall fields `A` and `B` from the client.  For administrator users, you'd want to marshall and unmarshall all fields.

You need to prevent leaking secure information to a Javascript-based client about field `C` when the user context isn't an administrator.  Preventing the insertion/update of field `C` for non-administrator users isn't sufficient depending on the secured nature of field `C`'s value.

Comment: Is there a way to do a role based marshalling during runtime? As of now marshalling is done by jackson based on the entity that the controller method holds - in my case all members of the entity (including the admin members).

Comment: ...and what happens when member c is not unmarshalled to the entity (due to a security rule) and the entity is written to the database? Will hibernate skip updating the column or will the column be overwritten with a null value?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too difficult:

1. With the same or different controller, create a separate API for reads/writes, one set for a normal user and the other set for admin users.
2. Use spring security to allow only Admins the ability to access the Admin APIs.
3. For the APIs handling the normal user reads, null out whatever elements of Z you don't want the normal user to see prior to sending the value out:

   ```
       @RequestMapping(value = "/my/foo/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public Foo getFoo(@PathVariable String id, HttpServletResponse response) {
           Foo foo = fooDao.getFoo(id);
           if (foo != null) {
               foo.setC(null);
               return foo;
           } else {
               response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
               return null;
           }
       }
   ```
4. For writes, retrieve the element from Hibernate based on the incoming object's internal ID and update it with only those fields from the incoming object that the user is allowed to update, then persist that object to the database.

Comment: This way seems to be redundant to me. I also considered to do this but i am not sure if this is good practice.Naros advice seems a better way to do this.

Comment: The portions of the two implementations that prove redundant can be factored out into a common private (non-externally available) method if desired.  But it seems more secure to me to have security based on the API URL (like lines 39-40 [here](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/b32c215e5c904070d02d6a837496819e05b953f4/app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/security.xml#L39)) so a method can't even be entered unless the roles are met, than to create a common method that all users can enter and rely on the method's implementation to ensure normal users aren't doing what only admins are allowed to.